# Is "Laudatio omnibus Dei" grammatically correct, or simply inane?

Tags: classical-latin

Is "Laudatio omnibus Dei" grammatically correct?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Latin.SE! Techinically it could be correct, though it sounds odd.What meaning do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It depends on what it should mean. Where does it come from? Is it a translation attempt of something? Please edit your question to add more details so you can get a useful answer.

Comment: It looks like "praise for all (people) of god." Depending on how it's intended to be used (aka as a command or a declarative statement) it could be correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Without more context, it is grammatically correct.

It would mean "praise for God [is] for all" (obj. gen.) or "God's praise [is] for all." (subj. gen.). It could even carry an implicit sense of responsibility, like "praise for God [is an obligation] for all."

I want, however, to question the use of *laudatio* instead of *laus, laudis*. *Laus* is the go-to Classical word for "commendation, glory, fame, renown, esteem," and even "praiseworthy things/deeds." [Laus, laudis lexicon entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=laus&la=la#lexicon)

*Laudatio* on the other hand is it's more abstract cousin. *Laudatio* means "praise" as a completed action, like "a praising." It lends itself, therefore, to meaning "a eulogy," "a panegyric," or even "favorable character testimony" in court. [Laudatio lexicon entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=laudatio&la=la#lexicon)

So unless you're talking about a specific prayer, you may want to consider changing *laudatio* to *laus.*